# Making td to display as block elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

**Hey programmers, I have this table code and I am using twitter bootstrap.
   I want when the table is viewed on a small screen,the first two td's remains inline
   whereas the third td goes to the next line; i.e.**

```
<my photo> <myname>   //the 1st td contains my photo,the second one my name and the 
<my description>      //the 3rd td contains my description but it's on the next line.
```

**here is my sample table:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>photo</td><td>name</td><td class="mylast">mydescription</td></tr>
</table>
```

**And here is my sample css:**

```
@media(max-width:767px)
{
 td.mylast{display:block;}
}
```

**I have tried quite some methods but no way, I have to seek help.
   please assist.**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.However I would not recommend changing how tables are intended to work. You can use grids to do the same.

```
   table{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
   }

   tr,td{
    display: block;

    }

   td{
     width: 50%;
     float: left;
    }

   td.myLast{
     width:100%;
     float:left;
     clear:both
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this**

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Photo</td>
<td>Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Description</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for that post but that would need two tr's. I wanted us to just have one tr with the last td being on a different line at small screens

Answer (score 0):

**@Neil,Thanks for help but since i had many td's I, i though i would tamper with the general layout of other areas. now i thought this way. i create another row hidden in large browsers but shown on small browsers. 
here is the sample:**

```
<table>
<tr><td>photo</td><td>name</td><td class="mylast">mydescription</td></tr>
<tr style="display:none;"><td colspan="3" class="medsmall">mydescription</td></tr>
</table>
```

**and my styles:**

```
@media(max-width:767px)
{
 td.mylast{display:none;}
 tr.medsmall{display:block;}
}
```

**i don't know your take but i need one more slight clarification if you don't mind: the tr doesn't display on media small(on resizing browser),i think i need to replace something in place of 
*tr.medsmall{display:block}*, because this is kind of telling the tr to display in block but not to show up;**